# Sorting lists in list by length using bubble sort - Haskell

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, multidimensional-array, functional-programming

I have an input, which is of type `[[a]]` and I am trying to sort the lists in the list by their length. I am working on my own implementation of bubble sort, which currently looks like this:

```
myInput :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
myInput [[]] = [[]]
myInput [[x]] = [[x]]
myInput (x : xs) = mySort x (myInput xs)

mySort :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
mySort x [[]] = [x]
mySort x (y:ys) | (length x) < (length y) = x:y:ys
                | otherwise = y:(myInput x ys)
```

However, when I input `myInput[[1,2],[1]]`, I get a non-exhaustive pattern error:

```
[[1]*** Exception: CourseworkRev.hs:(197,1)-(200,49): Non-exhaustive patterns in function myInput
```

I am probably doing something wrong when declaring the empty lists, as this is a recursion error (correct me if I am wrong). Any tips on how to make this working? Thanks!

Comment: `myInput` has no pattern for an empty list, only for a list with one element that is an empty list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tip! Do I correct it simply by `myInput [] = [[]]` ? I added this to my code, but I am still getting the same exhaustive pattern error

Comment: no `myInput [] = []`, and `myInput [x] = [x]`..

Comment: What is `myInsert`? If you're sorting solely by length, then the `Ord a` constraint is redundant. You should turn on `-Wall` so the compiler will give you detailed warnings about what patterns you've missed (along with other useful warnings). If you want only the pattern warnings, use `-Wincomplete-patterns -Wincomplete-uni-patterns`.

Comment: @dfeuer , yes, thank you for reminding me that, `Ord` was there because I also used the same function in previous assignment to sort elements in a list, so regarding this `-Wall` , do I just input my function with this flag? Such as `myInput[[1,2],[1]] -Wall` ? Thanks!

Comment: `-Wall` is a command line argument to ghc or ghci. Alternatively, you can put `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}` at the very tippy top of your `.hs` file. Or if you're using a Cabal file, let me know and I'll go remind myself how to stick it in there.

Comment: Also, in GHCi, you can at any time enter `:set -Wall`, but that will only give warnings for code entered/loaded *after* you enter that.

Comment: The Cabal file approach is usually best in a Cabal project. The `OPTIONS_GHC` approach is usually best otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myInput` has no pattern for an empty list, only for a list with one element that is an empty list. You likely do not need patterns like `[[]]` and `[[x]]` anyway, since for a list with a single element, you will return a list with that element, regardless of it length, so:

```
myInput :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
myInput [] = []
myInput [x] = [x]
myInput (x : xs) = mySort x (myInput xs)
```

`[[x]]` matches with a list that contains exactly one sublist `[x]` which is a list with one element. So this will match with `[[1]]`, but not with `[[1,2]]`. `[x]` on the other hand matches with any singleton list: a list with one element so `[[1]]`, `[[1,4]]`, `[[1,4,2,5]]`, and `[[]]` will all match.

Comment: Thank you very much, I also needed to change `mySort x [[]] = [x]` to `mySort x [] = [x]` and now it works perfectly. I see what I did wrong now, got really confused with the double brackets. Thanks a lot!